# Evaluating a surface integral in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $x=(x_{1},...,x_{n})$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n\geq2$), and $\alpha=(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n})$ is a multi index, we write $x^{\alpha}=x_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}...x_{n}^{\alpha_{n}}$.  How would you calculate the surface integral of $x^{\alpha}$ over the circle of radius $r>0$, i.e. 
 $$\int_{|x|=r}x^{\alpha}d\sigma?$$